# spark run on top of mesos - cluster mode - aws instances EC2 (1 master 1 slave)

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-ec2, cluster-computing, mesos, dispatcher

i am facing issue , i am trying to deploy a try out spark app (wordcount, written in java) 
i would run spark on top of mesos cluster (1 master, 1 agent slave) 
task failed, it seems master cant connect to mesos agent on port 5051, below the mesos error message 
 
Mesos and spark driver are showing that task is running but task cant complete
in slaves log, i have the message below 
 
**20/03/24 16:44:57 INFO TaskSchedulerImpl: Adding task set 0.0 with 1 tasks
20/03/24 16:45:12 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources**
 
 
instances are EC2 aws machine type: master, slave
mesos version : 1.4.1 and spark version is 2.4.4
thanks in advance of your help
let me know if more details you need 
 
mesos agent - connection with master error message :

[image]